# Sendgrid unsubscribe preferences

Tags: c#, smtp, sendgrid

I'm using Sendgrid and try to sending these emails with C# language.
So, what i'm doing is configure the SMTP and API Keys in my apps, and boom, there goes the emails were sent.

The question is, How do I insert the **Unsubscribe Preferences** group in my X-SMTPAPI header? 
FYI, unsubscribe preferences is where you can choose which group you want to unsubscribe instead of global unsubscribe.

I already checked these links:

- https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Suppression_Management/groups.html
- https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/requests.html
- https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/suppressions.html

I also checked the library C# on their github.
But none of these is made me clear.

I'm completely blind with JSON, GET, REQUEST, RESPONSE and such.

this is my C# code

```
        public void Main()
                {
                    string sSubject = Dts.Variables["vSubject"].Value.ToString();
                    string sBody = Dts.Variables["vBodyMessage"].Value.ToString();

                    int iPriority = 2;



                    if (SendMail(sSubject, sBody, iPriority))
                    {
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Fails the Task
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                    }
                }

//THIS IS THE HEADER X-SMTPAPI, I DUNNO HOW TO USE IT :(
//I WANNA ADD MY GROUPS HERE
    private static string XsmtpapiHeaderAsJson()
            {
                var header = new Header();
                header.SetAsmGroupId(777);

                //var uniqueArgs = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };
                //{

                //      "asm_groups_to_display": [1, 2, 3]

                //};
                //header.AddUniqueArgs({ "asm_groups_to_display": ['1', '2', '3']});

                //var subs = new List<String> { "私はラーメンが大好き" };
                //header.AddSubstitution("%tag%", subs);

                //dynamic stuff = json

                return header.JsonString();
            }

    public bool SendMail(string sSubject, string sMessage, int iPriority)
            {
                string xmstpapiJson = XsmtpapiHeaderAsJson();

                try
                {
                    string sEmailServer = Dts.Variables["sServer"].Value.ToString();
                    string sEmailPort = Dts.Variables["sPort"].Value.ToString();
                    string sEmailUser = Dts.Variables["sUser"].Value.ToString();
                    string sEmailPassword = Dts.Variables["sPassword"].Value.ToString();
                    string sEmailSendTo = Dts.Variables["sSendTo"].Value.ToString();
                    string sEmailSendToName = Dts.Variables["sSendToName"].Value.ToString();
                    //string sEmailSendCC = Dts.Variables["sSendCC"].Value.ToString();
                    string sEmailSendFrom = Dts.Variables["sFrom"].Value.ToString();
                    string sEmailSendFromName = Dts.Variables["sFromName"].Value.ToString();

                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

                    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(sEmailSendFrom, sEmailSendFromName);

                    //You can have multiple emails separated by ;
                    string[] sEmailTo = Regex.Split(sEmailSendTo, ";");
                    //string[] sEmailCC = Regex.Split(sEmailSendCC, ";");
                    int sEmailServerSMTP = int.Parse(sEmailPort);

                    smtpClient.Host = sEmailServer;
                    smtpClient.Port = sEmailServerSMTP;

                    System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredentials =
                       new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sEmailUser, sEmailPassword);
                    smtpClient.Credentials = myCredentials;

                    message.From = fromAddress;

                    //MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(sEmailSendTo, sEmailSendToName);
                    //message.To.Add(toAddress);

                    if (sEmailTo != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < sEmailTo.Length; ++i)
                        {
                            if (sEmailTo[i] != null && sEmailTo[i] != "")
                            {
                                MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(sEmailTo[i], sEmailSendToName);
                                message.To.Add(toAddress);


                            }
                        }
                    }

                    switch (iPriority)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            message.Priority = MailPriority.Low;
                            break;
                        default:
                            message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                            break;
                    }


                    //message.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", xmstpapiJson);

                    //smtpClient.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;
                    //const string state = "test1";

                    message.Subject = sSubject;
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    message.Body = sMessage;

                    //smtpClient.SendAsync(message, state);
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: hmm.. seems your issue is really in regards to `I'm completely blind with JSON, GET, REQUEST, RESPONSE and such`.  No offense, but providing a solution to this scenario isn't going to address that.  The documentation you referenced is adequate. Having said that, the referenced documentation is not in the context of this .NET `SmtpClient` Type instance or usage.  What is `header` in the static method named `XsmtpapiHeaderAsJson`?

Comment: Hi Brett, thank you for your response.
I'm trying my best to understand JSON GET etc, but without any simpler example/tutorial, I couldn't see how it goes. And, yes, XsmtpapiHeaderAsJson is my header, So I was hoping It could stored my Groups in there, and I just addHeader or something like that in SendMail down there..

Comment: the underline concept of RESTful APIs is that it relies on the http specification (which is a different protocol to smtp), thus the 'header' it is referencing is a http Request Header, (look up HttpRequest type in .NET). 

 I'm quite sure the SmtpClient you are initializing here is not establishing a connection over http, let alone being RESTFul. it's probably sending SOAP packets to Mail Server after establishing a connection on port 25 using the smtp (if we were to depict the connection as a url it would be `smtp://SERVERNAME:25`)

Comment: actually, I don't want to start you down the wrong path... my reference to HttpRequest Type was only to depict the notion of Request Headers.. but this type is used primarily in ASP.NET, or Web Application scenarios, where you're typically handling that Request..

Comment: one manner to make an http call would be to initialize an `HttpWebRequest` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.100).aspx to an endpoint..

Comment: oh, nevermind.. I can see after reviewing https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-csharp that I'm incorrect in some respects.. this a bit of an odd workflow. it's all about the json structure that is assigned to that smtp header..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see what you mean, the smtpapi-csharp project simply doesn't have that concept implemented.. but it's a trivial matter. (the value of this utility project is questionable to begin with).

Really the only piece of importance here is commented out.

```
//message.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", xmstpapiJson);
```

Should be,

```
message.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", @"{ ""asm_group_id"" : 777, ""asm_groups_to_display"" : [777] }");
```

Essentially, you're just assigning json to this header. The [Documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/suppressions.html) provides this sample

```
{
  "asm_groups_to_display": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

`[1, 2, 3]` is an array of integers, which correlates to GroupIds.

---

## Alternatively,

[fork the git](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-csharp) and add the following to `Header.cs`

```
/// <summary>
///     This sets which groups to display on the Manage Preferences page of an email.  You can find further documentation about ASM here:
///     https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/suppressions.html
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ids">ASM groups to display applied to the message</param>
public void SetAsmGroupsToDisplay(params int[] ids)
{
    _settings.AddArray(new List<string> {"asm_groups_to_display"}, ids);
}
```

Build and update your csproj reference to use your forked project.

then, call `SetAsmGroupsToDisplay` like so,

```
private static string XsmtpapiHeaderAsJson()
{
    var header = new Header();
    header.SetAsmGroupId(777);
    header.SetAsmGroupsToDisplay(777); // SetAsmGroupsToDisplay(new int[] {777}) works too
    return header.JsonString();
}
```

and, of course, use the method:

```
message.Headers.Add("X-SMTPAPI", XsmtpapiHeaderAsJson());
```

... don't forgot to add a Pull Request when you get it working.

Comment: this is the answer. Damn awesome, dude!! thanks for saving my life!!